# how much power incident from each line of gysel power divider?

Tags: power, temperature, transmission-line, microstrip

Consider we have equal power divider, So when we have 100 watts in port 1, this power split to two 50 watts in port2 and port 3.
for calculating how much temperature Rising in each transmission line, I should know how much power incident from each transmission line a. Temperature rise per RF Power is will be obtained with Microwave Impedance Calculator Software.
So, how should I know how much power incident from each line of gysel power divider?
[image]

Comment: You won't get 50 watts in P2 and P3 with 100 watts into P1.

Comment: you are Right, but my problem is not how much power I got in P1 and P2, right now